# When can you store Gyroids at The Roost?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

I know in City Folk you could store Gyroids with Brewster at the Roost.  I heard you can do the same thing in Animal Crossing: New Leaf.

Is this true?  What conditions have to be met in order to do so?

Comment: Not sure you can. I've gotten coffee for at least two weeks and still no gyroid storage. INstead you can work at the coffee shop, it seems.

Comment: That would be dissapointing.  :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It would appear you can't; searching online I've found no evidence of being able to do so (and the game's been out long enough people really should have found if there was a way).

Note you can still store Gyroids in the second floor of the museum, in your "closet" space at home, or with an alternate character. Since Brewster doesn't store them, I've taken to storing them on an alternate character along with other rarely used items.

Comment: Also, you can store four at Club LOL.

Answer (score 0):

That's only in city folk. I heard if you work there a lot then he gives you rare Brewster gyroids that make pouring noises

Answer (score -2):

It turns out, however, that Brewster (owner of the Roost coffee shop) is really into collecting gyroids.  He will store your gyroids in his back room for you if you bring them to him.

Brewster will only offer to do this after he has gotten to know you.  Thus, you must drink seven cups of coffee (while they are hot, don't tell him you are going to wait for it to cool).  You can only drink one cup a day, so it will take you at least seven days to do this.  After your seventh, put your gyroids in your pocket and go talk to Brewster (from the side of his counter, don't sit in the chair).  He will offer to store them.  From now on, just go to his counter with all your gyroids and he will store them.  Then you can view them and pick the ones you want to take out for your house.

[Source](http://www.animalcrossingpost.com/articles/gyroids.php).

Comment: I suspect this is City Folk